# Yii, MongoDB query Subdocuments for insertion in a Mysql Table

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, yii

I'm doing a project using Yii Framework, MySQL and MongoDB. I need to get the data from a collection of the mongo database and insert the records in a mysql table. The document of mongodb has subdocuments and I need to insert a row in mysql for every subdocument in the collection. The code of my project is:

```
    $query = array('year'=>'2014');
    $records = Yii::app()->edmsMongoCollection('DocumentosDesgloseER')->find($query);       

    foreach($records as $data){
        $success = false;
        $model = new DesgloseAcumulado;
        $atributos['Id_Enterprise'] = $data['id_enterprise'];
        $atributos['Id_Store'] = $data['id_store'];
        $atributos['Month'] = $data['month'];
        $atributos['Year'] = $data['year'];
        $atributos['Id_Usuario'] = Yii::app()->user->id;
        $atributos['Id_RubroER'] = $data['DocumentosDesgloseER'][0]['id_rubroer'];
        $i = $i + 1;
        $model->attributes = $atributos;
        if($model->save()) {
            $success = true;
        }
    }
```

And the structure of my collection in mongodb is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("535fe63acac5853943166f5c"),
"DocumentosDesgloseER" : [ 
    {
        "elemento" : "VENTAS NETAS",
        "id_rubroer" : "45",
        "id_documento_consolidados_temp" : "31809",
        "abreviatura" : "VN",
        "orden" : "1",
        "formula" : "(250*CM)",
        "tipo_fila" : "1",
        "resultado_actual" : "113.628",
        "resultado_ant" : "239.851",
        "promedio_mensual_actual" : "111.365",
        "ppto_mes_actual" : "131.540",
        "real_acumulado_actual" : "556.826",
        "real_acumulado_ant" : "965.824",
        "ppto_acumulado_actual" : "666.805"
    }, 
    {
        "elemento" : "RUBRO DE PRUEBAS",
        "id_rubroer" : "19",
        "id_documento_consolidados_temp" : "31810",
        "abreviatura" : "RP",
        "orden" : "3",
        "formula" : "CM/500",
        "tipo_fila" : "1",
        "resultado_actual" : "71.057",
        "resultado_ant" : "281.697",
        "promedio_mensual_actual" : "67.090",
        "ppto_mes_actual" : "72.347",
        "real_acumulado_actual" : "335.448",
        "real_acumulado_ant" : "879.719",
        "ppto_acumulado_actual" : "366.743"
    }
],
"documentoID" : "4DOTA2",
"id_enterprise" : "1",
"id_store" : "24",
"month" : "Importes2",
"year" : "2014",
"lastMonthNumber" : NumberLong(4)
```

}

This is only one of the documents in the collection. As I said earlier, I need to save a row for every subdocument for each document in the mysql database. My code save only the data of the document and the id_rubroer of the subdocument "0".

Does anyone know how I can make the For Loop for each subdocument rather than for each object (document)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for-loop the "sub-documents"... say:

```
foreach($records['DocumentosDesgloseER'] as $data){
        $success = false;
        $model = new DesgloseAcumulado;
        $atributos['Id_Enterprise'] = $data['id_enterprise'];
        $atributos['Id_Store'] = $data['id_store'];
        $atributos['Month'] = $data['month'];
        $atributos['Year'] = $data['year'];
        $atributos['Id_Usuario'] = Yii::app()->user->id;
        $atributos['Id_RubroER'] = $data['id_rubroer'];
        $i = $i + 1;
        $model->attributes = $atributos;
        if($model->save()) {
            $success = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I'm getting an error when executing the code (Internal Error Server 500). Thanks for your response anyway :)

Comment: Actually, I already resolved my problem doing some changes in your response. Thanks again. I did two foreach: